# GROUP BY - inline view and unjoined tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following ORACLE query where I attempt to find the department with the highest average salary. I would like to use in-line view (i.e. retain the b dataset) for this implementation, but struggle to get the right part at the WHERE and GROUP BY components. I know the below GROUP BY and WHERE (which is non-existant) is wrong. But how do i correct them?

```
select a.deptno from emp a, 
(select max(avg_sal) max_avg_sal from (select  
avg(sal) avg_sal from emp group by deptno) ) b 
group by a.deptno, b.max_avg_sal 
having avg(a.sal) = b.max_avg_sal
```

**Expected Result**

```
deptno
10
```

**Emp Structure**

```
deptno staff sal
10     A     1000
10     B     1500
11     C     1100
12     D     1000
12     E     900
12     F     1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, avg(e.salary) over (partition by e.deptno) as avg_salary
      from emp e
     ) e
order by avg_salary desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

`fetch first` is available in Oracle 12c+.  You can do similar things with an additional subquery in earlier versions.

Comment: Can you do one without using windowing function ? ,

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery

```
select deptno from tablename
group by deptno
having avg(sal)= (select max(asal) from (select avg(sal) as asal from tablename group by deptdno)A)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is one approach, however I am trying to have the subquery to be an inline view to see if it's implementable.

Answer (score 0):

The straight-forward way is:

```
select deptno
from emp
group by deptno
order by avg(salary) desc
fetch first row with ties;
```

`FETCH FIRST` is available as of Oracle 12c.

In Oracle 11g we could use this instead:

```
select deptno
from
(
  select deptno, avg(salary) as avg_salary, max(avg(salary)) over () as max_avg_salary
  from emp
  group by deptno
)
where avg_salary = max_avg_salary;
```

But you want an inline view, another word for a derived table (a subquery in the from clause). That looks way more clumsy. One example without `FETCH FIRST` and without window functions:

```
with d as
(
  select deptno, avg(salary) as avg_salary
  from emp
  group by deptno
)
, dmax as
(
  select max(avg_salary) as max_avg_salary
  from d
)
select d.*
from d
join dmax on dmax.max_avg_salary = d.avg_salary;
```

I find this very obfuscated and don't recommend it at all. You can do the same without `WITH` clauses of course. Then it is even less readable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you'd want to write it this way, but if you really want only inline views and no windowing clauses, you can write it this way:

```
select b.deptno 
from   (SELECT deptno, avg(sal) avgsal from emp group by deptno ) b
cross join (SELECT max(avgsal) maxavgsal FROM (SELECT avg(sal) avgsal FROM emp group by deptno )) c
where  b.avgsal = c.maxavgsal;
```

This the same thing, if you don't like `CROSS JOIN` for some reason:

```
select b.deptno 
from   (SELECT deptno, avg(sal) avgsal from emp group by deptno ) b
inner join ( SELECT max(avgsal) maxavgsal FROM 
   ( SELECT avg(sal) avgsal FROM emp group by deptno ) ) c
on b.avgsal = c.maxavgsal;
```